# Read and write and submit on a webpage from java

Tags: java, javascript, html, http

How can I read a web page using Java, write data to form elements, submit the form, and read the returned webpage?

To be specific, I want to view a student's results from a university website by entering the student's registration number, submitting it, and reading the result page.

How would it be possible to implement this?

Comment: You should be more specific because SO users can't understand whether you want to develop a website or test it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [HttpUnit](http://httpunit.sourceforge.net/), which is a library primarily for testing web sites.  But it would be perfect for your scenario, too.

Example:

```
WebConversation wc = new WebConversation();
WebResponse top     = wc.getResponse( "http://www.meterware.com/Frames.html" ); // read a page with two frames
WebResponse summary = wc.getFrameContents( "summary" );                         // read the summary frame
WebLink     link    = summary.getLinkWith( "Cake Recipe" );                     // find the link (which targets "details" );
link.click();                                                                   // click on it
WebResponse response= wc.getFrameContents( "details" );                         // retrieve the details frame
```

**Edit**

And then there is [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/).  I guess it is a matter of taste.